# Redux call function on change

Tags: redux, react-redux

I started using `Redux` with `React`. My Store contains several job Objects each with an id. I want to call a function, whenever I `add/update` a new Job. What's the recommended way to do so?

Here's my reducer

```
function reducer(state:= {}, action) {
const {  id, fields } = action.payload

switch (action.type) {
    case ADDED:
      if (!state[id]) {
            return {
                ...state,
                [id]: fields,
                },
            };
        } else {
            const currentDate = moment(stat[id].lastModified)
            const newDate = moment(fields.metaData.lastModified);
            if (!currentDate.isSame(newDate)) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    [id]: { ...state[id], ...fields },
                    },
                };
            }

            // don't update otherwise
            return state;
        } 
  case OTHERS:
            ......
}
```

Whenever something is added, I add it to the state, if it already exists but the modificationDate is newer, I update it in the state. I want my function to the called in either `ADDED` cases

Answer (score 0):

Reducers must do only state update (no more). It seems you need using Redux middleware for that

Comment: can you give me a recommendation or an example for a middleware?